# Form field using UTF-8 characters results in error 404 when the form is submitted

Tags: forms, utf-8, character-encoding, http-status-code-404

We have a UTF-8 encoded page, UTF-8 encoded database and all tables yet when one of the forms on our website contains UTF-8 characters (in our case Czech letters) and is then submitted the page shown is error 404. Without the Czech letters the form submits as it should. Any idea what I have overlooked? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could try making your form look like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

However, please refer also to:

- [Is there any benefit to adding accept-charset="UTF-8" to HTML forms, if the page is already in UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719974/is-there-any-benefit-to-adding-accept-charset-utf-8-to-html-forms-if-the-page)
- [HTML form, character sets, and the accept-charset attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582309/html-form-character-sets-and-the-accept-charset-attribute)

I would also do some packet-level debugging using something like Wireshark to see if the problem is with the browser not encoding the text as you'd expect - or if the server is receiving the encoding properly, but is failing to properly decode it.

Comment: It's odd though because other fields in the form are fine (when using Czech characters)! Unfortunately adding `accept-charset="UTF-8"` didn't work in this case.

Comment: @JoeW - You need to follow my debugging recommendation to at least narrow this down to the browser or the server.  (My guess is that something with your server code is not decoding the field properly.)